# 'in' is never closed

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, drjava

there is a error in my code it is giving me a warning

Warning: Resource leak: 'in' is never closed

I have never had this problem before, in fact I tried old programs that I have written and it is still giving me the same issue. How do I fix this ?

```
import java.util.Scanner ;


public class CountVowels
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
      String word = in.next();

      int vowelCount = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
      {
         char currentCharacter = word.charAt(i);
         if (currentCharacter == 'a' || currentCharacter == 'A'
            || currentCharacter == 'e' || currentCharacter == 'E'
            || currentCharacter == 'i' || currentCharacter == 'I'
            || currentCharacter == 'o' || currentCharacter == 'O'
            || currentCharacter == 'u' || currentCharacter == 'U')
         {
            vowelCount++;
         }
      }
      System.out.println(vowelCount + " vowel(s).");



   }
}
```

Comment: Close it? Or, even better, use `try`-with-resources to close it automatically.

Comment: Warnings aren't the same as errors.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will just need to close your scanner at the end of your function with:

```
in.close();
```

Like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   // Do some stuff using the scanner
   in.close();
}
```

And also take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613626/scanner-is-never-closed).

Comment: +1, yup :). Even better would be for him to use a `try/catch` statement and also could add a `finally` to close the scanner