# resource leak 'Nommy' is never closed error

Tags: java

i'm new to java so please do explain in full were i'm going wrong
thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class apples {
public static void main (String args[]){
Scanner Nommy = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println (Nommy.nextLine());
  }
}
```

Comment: This should help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/15613676/1547337

Comment: sorry still dont get it, could you explain were i'm going wrong please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should [`close`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close%28%29) the scanner after using it. Otherwise, you'll get the warning from the compiler.

The simplest way is to add `Nommy.close()` after the last statement.

You should, however, call it in a `finally` block or using the `try` statement: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15613676/1547337

Comment: now ive close it, when i press run its giving this error "Error: Could not find or load main class Port" what dose this mean?

Comment: That's because your class name is not Port, but apples. Try `java apples`

Comment: sorry but what is is port?

Comment: That's what I should ask you. It's something that doesn't exist. You can see it from the error.

Answer (score 1):

To understand what's wrong, you should learn more about `streams` stuff.

Briefly, if you `open` stream, then, you should `close` it, or a memory leak appears.

See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_files_io.htm for details.

Good luck!