# Why does eclipse say the scanner is never closed when it is?

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse says the scanner is never closed, and prompts me to suppress it, but it is closed.

```
public boolean hasPlayerAlreadyJoined(Player p) {
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(joinedPlayers);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String name = scanner.nextLine();
            if (name.equals(p.getName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
    } catch(Exception e){}
    return false;
}
```

I am guessing it is because of the while loop but I have never ran into an error like this before. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Check [Scanner is never closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613626/scanner-is-never-closed)

Comment: Never do this: `catch(Exception e){}`. Please.

Answer (score 1):

put `scanner.close();` inside the a `finally` clause so that it would be called at the end. It's the most optimal way :

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(joinedPlayers);
try {
   ....
}
catch(...) {
   ....
}
finally {
    scanner.close();
}
```

Comment: Isn't it better to use try with resources?

Comment: It's better but It's restricted to Java 7.